# Form fields from the ASP.NET View appear NULL in the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

The form fields do not return the value of the form even thought the asp-controller and asp-action is stated.
 The form does go to the right controller function and returns the right view, however, it does the form object is NULL.

```
@using ActionAugerMVC.Models
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<Cities>,Content,IEnumerable<Content>,Quote>
@addTagHelper "*,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"

 <div class="sidebar__item">
    <p class="subheading">Instant Quote Request</p>
       <form class="register__form" role="form" asp-controller="Plumbing" asp-action="QuoteForm" method="post">
             <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
             <div class="form-group">

               <label class="sr-only">Full Name </label>
               <input asp-for="@Model.Item4.FullName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="sr-only">Your phone</label>
                 <input asp-for="@Model.Item4.Phone" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your phone">
                 <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Item4.Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="sr-only">E-mail</label>
                 <input asp-for="@Model.Item4.Email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail">
                 <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Item4.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="sr-only">Your Message</label>
                 <input asp-for="@Model.Item4.Message" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message">
               </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Get a Quote Now" class="btn btn-accent btn-block">
         </form>
   </div> <!-- .sidebar__item -->
```

And the Controller looks like this, with the Quote object being null.
The hard coded, values appear correctly in the view, but the Quote object returned by the form is null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult QuoteForm(Quote quote)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           /* quote.FullName = "Umar Aftab";
            quote.Email = "test@email.com";
            quote.City = "Calgary";
            quote.Message = "Test Message";
            quote.Phone = "6474543769";
            */

        }
        return View(quote);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your use of a Tuple as your view's model combined with `asp-for`. For example, with something like:

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Item4.FullName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name">
```

The name of the input is going to end up as `Item4.FullName`. However, your action accepts only `Quote`, which means the modelbinder needs the input to be named just `FullName` in order to bind it properly. You either need to accept the same model the view uses (though I've never tried posting a `Tuple` so not sure if that will even work), or you can use a partial view to work around the issue.

Essentially, you just would need to move all the fields related to just `Quote` to a partial view. Then, in this view, you can include them via:

```
@Html.Partial("_QuoteFields", Model.Item4)
```

That *should* be enough psych Razor out enough to just name the fields like `FullName` instead of `Item4.FullName`. If it's not, then you may need to reset the `HtmlFieldPrefix`, via:

```
@Html.Partial("_QuoteFields, Model.Item4, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo {  HtmlFieldPrefix = "" } })
```

Comment: the form is in the sidebar of the page. I tried using a partial view, but than the main view references a tuple and the partial view references Quote model, this is something asp.net engine does not accept.

Comment: It's not a problem if you just pass in the  quote portion of the main views model. If you pass in the entire model, or don't pass a model at all (which implicitly passes in the main views model), then yes you'll get an exception.

Comment: How do I access the quote portion of the tuple in the partial view ?

Comment: Exactly as I showed you: `@Html.Partial("_QuoteFields", Model.Item4)`. That second parameter is the model for the partial view, which since just `Item4` is being passed, will be just the `Quote` piece.

Comment: And the reference on the partial view can be `@model ActionAugerMVC.Models.Quote` , is this correct

Comment: Guess what, I was doing exactly that and I was wondering why it wasn't working. It was because I had to add `@addTagHelper "*,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"` to the partial view and like you said I had to pass the model `@Html.Partial("_QuoteFields", Model.Item4)`. Thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155549/discussion-between-umar-aftab-and-chris-pratt).

Answer (score 0):

The model on your view is different than the model you're trying to bind it to in the controller. You're not going to get the key/value pairs to match up

Put your razor in a partial view with `Quote` as the model and try that.

**_QuoteForm.cshtml**

```
@model Quote

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">Full Name </label>
    <input asp-for="FullName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">Your phone</label>
    <input asp-for="Phone" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your phone">
    <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">E-mail</label>
    <input asp-for="Email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail">
    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">Your Message</label>
    <input asp-for="Message" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message">
</div>
```

**OriginalView.cshtml**

```
using ActionAugerMVC.Models
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<Cities>,Content,IEnumerable<Content>,Quote>
@addTagHelper "*,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"

<div class="sidebar__item">
    <p class="subheading">Instant Quote Request</p>
    <form class="register__form" role="form" asp-controller="Plumbing" asp-action="QuoteForm" method="post">
         <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

         @Html.Partial("_QuoteForm", Model.Item4)

         <input type="submit" value="Get a Quote Now" class="btn btn-accent btn-block">
    </form>
</div> <!-- .sidebar__item -->
```

Comment: I am actually working with multiple models within the same view. That's why I have a tuple.

Comment: A tuple is actually a very poor way to do that. It's far better to just have a class that encapsulates everything and then use that as the model. Then your items have explicit names like Quote instead of Item4, which makes it a ton easier to tell what you're working with.

Comment: I already have a View Model setup which has 3 different models in there. I did not try that out, let me see.